# primefaces inputText enter string, but only allow digits

Tags: jsf, primefaces, integer, size, bean-validation

I have a primefaces p:inputText where I want the user to enter an integer, but the type of the data must remain a string as I use server-side bean validation with  @javax.validation.constraints.Size (Thats why integer converters do not work, I get an ClassCastExcpetion from the Hibernate validator). I do that because the seam bean is also used to store string on other occasions.

Ideally, I want that the user can only enter digits in the field, therefore I played with "onkeypressed" and different regexes/keycodes, but I could not found a solution that worked on Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I experimented with f:validateRegex, but strangely the validation does only work if I omit the type="number" in p:inputText. Also the posted solution of Paul Wasilewski does not work in the case of input="number" (at least on firefox)

Comment: @Kukeltje: thanks for the advice, but I did not manage to make a mask with unlimitied number of digits, can you help?

Comment: you can use javascript function below link example you can solved it https://kurtomerfaruk.wordpress.com/2014/03/09/primefaces-spinnera-sadece-sayi-girmek/

Comment: @Kukeltje: yes thats what I tried

Comment: @Kukeltje: If you know the answer, then give an answer. We are not in kidnergarden here

Comment: No I DO NOT KNOW THE ANSWER, but I have no intention to try everything that you already tried and that did not work...  [ask] (first lines, about keeping track etc...) Good luck

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Comment: @Kukeltje: Sorry, I misinterpredted your comments (I was in a rather bad mood yesterday because of several bug in our code :)

Comment: @RaphaelRoth, I have update my answer. This solution should work in every browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not tried it already. A solution would be

```
<p:inputText ... onkeydown="return event.keyCode &gt;= 48 &amp;&amp; event.keyCode &lt;= 57 || event.keyCode == 8" ... />
```

Comment: I get the following error: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

Comment: thanks, it works (unless one used type="number", then i can type commas in Firefox).